# How do i format date in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

whenever i use this code

```
NSString *theDateS = [name valueForKey:@"startDate"];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
        NSDate *theDateFormatted = [dateFormat dateFromString: theDateS];
```

I got an error message 
"NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9249290'"

I was trying to change format 2014-06-10 16:00:00 +0000 to format 2014-06-10 04:00:00 PM pls help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire block of code can simply be:

```
NSDate *date = name[@"startDate"];
```

Since the error indicates that you are actually getting an `NSDate` from your `name` dictionary.

Keep in mind that if you simply use `NSLog` on the `NSDate`, it will be shown in UTC format.

If you want to convert the date to a specific string format for display to the user, then update your code as follows:

```
NSDate *date = name[@"startDate"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *theDateFormatted = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: instead of having a value of 2014-06-10 04:00:00 PM it returns 2014-06-11 12:00:00 AM, meaning hours are wrong

Comment: It all depends on your timezone. You say that logging the original date gives you `2014-06-10 16:00:00 +0000`. This is 4pm in UTC. If your timezone is UTC+8 then getting a final result of `2014-06-11 12:00:00 AM` is correct.

Comment: OMG This is embarrassing but I was looking on the other date! totally blown away. thanks for this :*

Answer (score 3):

The variable `theDateS` is not what you think it is:

```
NSString * theDateS = [name valueForKey:@"startDate"];
```

It is actually an `NSDate`, not an `NSString`. Obj-c can be weird like that.

If you need to format it into an `NSString`, that's a pretty well researched topic on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSDateFormatter

Comment: tried that, but when I do that it outputs this: 2014-03-29 00:08:13.539 Syd Table View[2567:60b] 2014-06-11 12:00:00 AM

Comment: its not getting proper hour and minute..how can I do that?

Comment: is the issue that you want an `NSString` representation of your date in a certain format? Or is it that you think your date is inaccurate?

Comment: Your date will be shown in UTC if you write it to NSLog. If you need to display it in your app in some other format check the link I provided and @rmaddy's answer.

Comment: instead of having a value of 2014-06-10 04:00:00 PM it returns 2014-06-11 12:00:00 AM, meaning hours are wrong.

Comment: Your date's hours are not wrong, your date is correct. It's just that when you print it out it is shown in UTC. Are you sure that `theDateS` object is accurate for your current locale?